# Not able to save userId generated from DB to android

Tags: php, android

Hello I'm new to android and developed a simple app to interact with a local server written in php and communicate with my DB. I am able to store a user basic information. Now i want to retrieve userId from the db but having trouble storing the userId generated by DB to User Object. AsyncTask takes the parameter of User. User contains basic properties such as first name and LastName. The DB generates userId but i want to retrieve the Id because i have another table to post an event that takes the userId as a foreign key. I am able to get a response from php and display the userId but not able to save it in user object. Please what am i doing wrong.

Below is my code:

```
public class HttpRequestUser extends AsyncTask<User, Void, String> {

    String urlparameter="";

  HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
  URL url =null;
  DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=null;
    BufferedReader reader;
    String output="";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(User... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL("****************************/userInfo.php");
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            User user = params[0];
            jsonObject.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
            jsonObject.put("lastName", user.getLastName());

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

           //getting response from php and able to display userId
            output= reader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
           Log.d("User id: ", output); //can display userId generated by database

            user.setUserId(output); //tried assigning the userId here to no avail

        }
        catch(MalformedURLException ex){

        }
        catch(IOException ex) {

        }
        catch(JSONException ex){

        }
        finally {
            try {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    private String reader(InputStream inputStream) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try{
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String output="";
            while((output=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null) {
                stringBuilder.append(output);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
              ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use shared preference to store user info

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("user_Info", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putInt("User_Id", user_id);
                    editor.putString("Addresss", address);
                    editor.commit();
```

To retrieve values

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("user_Info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                     int user_id = (shared.getInt("User_Id", 0));
                     string address = (shared.getString("Addresss"));
```

Comment: Do i add shared preference in the model class?

Comment: when attempting to try your solution i placed getApplicationContext() right after getting the userId but having error has it fails to recognize getApplicationContext()